# Installing as many dependencies as possible for pip package using Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

When I use conda environments I often find myself using packages that are only on PyPI requiring pip to install them, but for which many of the dependencies could be installed using conda. If I just install them using pip I'll end up with an environment with several pip-managed packages.

Currently I have to start a pip install (say for `torchkge`), and notice that it requires for instance `pandas` and starts downloading it. I `ctrl+C` and then `conda install pandas` before redoing the pip install until I see that pip sees that all of the dependencies are satisfied and none need to be installed.

Is there a simple way of doing this dependency check and installing the available dependencies with conda?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command. For example if I need to check dependencies of Pandas:

```
pip show pandas
```

In result set you will find the modules required under `Requires` keyword.

OR

You can also use `pipdeptree`

```
$ pip install pipdeptree
```

then run

```
$ pipdeptree
```

and it will show you your dependencies in a tree form.

For pandas you can check:

```
$ pipdeptree -p pandas
```

Comment: `pipdeptree` doesn't work unless the package is already installed, and also doesn't give me a clean output that I can feed to `conda`.